# Direction of Coriolis force

Tags: forces, reference-frames, vectors, earth, coriolis-effect

My doubt is all about finding the direction of coriolis force by using the direction of the moving object. I really find it difficult to determine the direction of coriolis force through direction of moving object. Because, the direction of the moving object is given in the form of degree and that too in a confusing way. For instance, an object is moving at 60°N latitude/colatitude. Here direction of the moving object is given in the form of latitude which is very confusing to me and just because of that I don't know how to find the direction of coriolis force?

Answer (score 1):

Use 3-dimensional vectors and study the vector cross-product. The Coriolis force vector is proportional to $\mathbf{v}\times \mathbf{\omega}$, where $\mathbf{v}$ is the object's velocity vector, and $\mathbf{\omega}$ is the angular rotation vector of the coordinate frame as seen from an inertial frame.

Answer (score 0):

On the Earth's surface, the direction of Corriolis force is only dependent on componets of motion that alters an objects distance to the axis of rotation of the earth.

Corriolis acts either East or West. When moving towards the equator the radius of rotation increases, a body must accelerate East to continue to orbit once per day.  When moving away from the equator the radius of rotation decreases, the object must accelerate West in order to slow down so that it orbits once per day.

The magnitude of the corriolis force also depends upon Latitude.Near the poles Coriolis effects are larger. So you need to know the Latitude of the object as well as its direction of motion to calculate coriolis effects. It sounds like that's what $60^\circ$N Latitude means, and there should be other direction information in the question if you have to calaculate Coriolis force, direction and also speed.

Try this picture 
[image]

Z is up, y is north, x is east ($\psi$ is Latitude and $\omega$ is angualr velocity). Notice how the northern blue circle has a smaller circumference than the one at the equator, but it still rotates once per day. Objects moving north from the equator have to be slowed down to stay stationary on the surface of the earth.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By your answer, I can understand the concept much better than before but my knowledge is not that developed to understand exactly what you say.

Comment: Added a picture.

Comment: thanks for the picture. From that, I understand that the direction of the object should always be taken along y axis (i.e) if object is travelling due south then y axis should lie in that direction.

Comment: In the diagram the Y axis points north parallel to the ground (sphere surface).

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you've launched a projectile from the equator directly towards the North Pole. The Earth's circumference at the equator is 24,901 miles, so let's say, for the sake of argument (and because it's a nice round number) that the speed at the equator is 1,000 miles per hour. Your projectile will therefore have an eastern velocity of 1,000 mph (the speed of the equator). As your projectile passes over 45° north latitude it will still have that eastern velocity of 1,000 mph, but the ground under it will be travelling at about 707 mph (cosine of 45°). In other words, the projectile will be travelling about 293 mph faster in an eastern direction than the ground.
It's a simple thought experiment to do in the opposite direction and south of the equator.